# How to uncompress mysql string in delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

I want to compress MySQL result or string inside MySQL query and the result will send to delphi application. I use this to speed up connectivity. 
The problem is how to uncompress string from MySQL result inside delphi.

Here is my sample query

```
Select Compress(AColumn), Compress(BColumn) from ATable
```

Comment: Isn't that something that you specify in connection string ? For instance with [`FireDAC`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)) you can specify the `Compress` parameter for network traffic compression.

Comment: You are expected to use DECOMPRESS to reverse the compression. Are you quite sure that this functionality is what you need. I think its intended use is to save space server side. Are you even sure that the compression happens server side?

Comment: Oops, I mean UNCOMPRESS

Comment: yes david. in mysql result i think is small data that send to client. and i think this can faster connection. so i need delphi procedure (not mysql function) that can uncompress mysql string

Comment: According to the MySQL docs you use the MySQL command UNCOMPRESS

Answer (score 3):

**Compress is for storage**
The `compress` keyword in MySQL is not meant to reduce network traffic, but rather to reduce storage requirements.
The details of the compression are not documented and may vary from server to server.

> `COMPRESS(string_to_compress)`
>
> Compresses a string and returns the result as a binary string. This function requires MySQL to have been compiled with a compression library such as zlib. Otherwise, the return value is always NULL. The compressed string can be uncompressed with `UNCOMPRESS()`.

Note that the ability to uncompress depends on the compression library that your MySQL version was compiled with.

**Modify the connection string if you want network compression**
If you want to compress the network data you specify this in the connection settings:
Add the following string to the `Properties` property.
`UseCompression = true;`

[image]

A list of all connection properties can be found here:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

More info can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectionstring
*(note that this info is quite old, but I'm tweaking the url for the newer versions results in a 404 page not found error).*

Note that in Delphi the `connectionstring` is largly filed in by the properties:
- Database
- Port
- Password
etc
In the `Properties` property you only supply those `ConnectionString` options that Delphi does not already cover in its other properties. Multiple arguments are separated by a `;`.

**Further complications**
Different component packs use different names for the extra data you can put into the ConnectionString.
ZEOS calls it `properties`
Other people call it other things.

Comment: i have use mydac Tmyconnection and in the option is include compress to. but the speed still not i expected. is there another way to uncompress mysql string inside delphi?

Comment: @roro, not that I know of. I seriously doubt your custom code is going to improve on the standard network compression code though.

Comment: @Johan, it makes me wonder, what they do with `Compress` parameter in FireDAC. They specifically say *"Specify True to enable network traffic compression."* in [`the docs`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)). So either the docs is wrong or there is some parameter for only network traffic compression.

Comment: @Johan, oh, now I see that. The `Compress` parameter in FireDAC is the [`MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-options.html) option in MySQL which is not implemented...

Comment: @Tlama. can you explain about your last comment?

Comment: @Roro, sorry for misleading, I missed that `argument:` part of that `argument: not used` note thinking this parameter is not used (in the meaning of not implemented). Well, then it might be what you're looking for; a parameter that enables compressed client/server protocol.